# How to draw vertical line in TeeChart?

Tags: c#, teechart

I have a TeeChart (C#.NET) with 1-5 line series. Its X axis is type of DateTime, and Y is Double.

I want to draw vertical lines to mark interesting time positions, like start and end of sequences, but I can't find a method for drawing vertical lines. Am I just blind or do I need to detour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [ColorLine tool](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/net/lib/html/SteemaTeeChartToolsColorLine.htm&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjXh7qT0pXLAhUThhoKHeOgAtUQFggKMAM&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNH6hPrVFNkI8XS9jv8NqVdmc7uQaQ) for that. You'll find examples at *All Features\Welcome !\Tools\Color Line* in the features demo, available at TeeChart's program group and more info at the [TeeChart .NET tutorials](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/net/tutorials/), specifically at tutorial number 18.

Comment: Hey thank you! I got it close, but when i put `colorLine.Value = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 34, 0);` I get error _Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'double'_ so which kind of conversion would help me out?

Comment: Also `Convert.ToDouble(DateTime)`complains invalid cast.

Comment: @Travenin you should use [DateTime.ToOADate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yess, I just found it at the same time you commented. Thanks!